# "И днем(,) и ночью кот ученый..."

Tags: пунктуация

На одном сообществе задали вопрос на засыпку: нужна ли запятая между "и днем(,) и ночью"? Мне кажется, что нет, а что скажут специалисты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна.
Если на вскидку - то по причине тесного фразеологического единства "дня" и "ночи".

Может, еще какое обоснование есть. Говорю только потому, что "вопрос на засыпку", а больше тут сыпаться не на чем.

//------------
Примечание. Если повторяющимися союзами и, ни соединены два однородных члена с противоположными значениями, образующие одно цельное выражение, то запятая между ними не ставится, например:

```
ни то ни се, и так и этак, ни тот ни другой, ни да ни нет, и день и ночь, и стар и млад, и смел и горе, ни жив ни мертв, ни взад ни вперед, ни рыба ни мясо, ни дать ни взять.
```

Запятая не ставится также между двумя однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимся союзом и образующими тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например:

```
Были и лето и осень дождливы.
Жуковский
```

//------------
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_27